# How to return previous element from group where some column is True

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame is as follows:

```
ex = {'group': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0', 5: '0', 6: '0', 7: '0', 8: '0', 9: '0', 10: '0', 11: '0', 12: '0', 13: '0', 14: '0', 15: '0', 16: '0', 17: '0', 18: '0', 19: '0', 20: '0', 21: '1', 22: '1', 23: '1', 24: '1', 25: '1', 26: '1', 27: '1', 28: '1', 29: '1', 30: '1', 31: '1', 32: '1', 33: '1', 34: '1', 35: '1', 36: '1', 37: '1', 38: '1', 39: '1'}, 'order': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 0, 22: 1, 23: 2, 24: 3, 25: 4, 26: 5, 27: 6, 28: 7, 29: 8, 30: 9, 31: 10, 32: 11, 33: 12, 34: 13, 35: 14, 36: 15, 37: 16, 38: 17, 39: 18}, 'id': {0: '102', 1: '302', 2: '302', 3: '302', 4: '102', 5: '302', 6: '302', 7: '302', 8: '302', 9: '302', 10: '102', 11: '308', 12: '308', 13: '308', 14: '308', 15: '302', 16: '102', 17: '302', 18: '102', 19: '302', 20: '102', 21: '102', 22: '102', 23: '308', 24: '312', 25: '312', 26: '312', 27: '308', 28: '102', 29: '302', 30: '312', 31: '302', 32: '302', 33: '102', 34: '102', 35: '302', 36: '312', 37: '308', 38: '102', 39: '302'}, 'type': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'D', 5: 'E', 6: 'D', 7: 'E', 8: 'A', 9: 'E', 10: 'E', 11: 'D', 12: 'A', 13: 'A', 14: 'A', 15: 'D', 16: 'D', 17: 'D', 18: 'A', 19: 'D', 20: 'A', 21: 'D', 22: 'F', 23: 'A', 24: 'D', 25: 'A', 26: 'E', 27: 'A', 28: 'E', 29: 'D', 30: 'E', 31: 'E', 32: 'G', 33: 'A', 34: 'D', 35: 'D', 36: 'H', 37: 'I', 38: 'A', 39: 'E'}, 'of_interest': {0: False, 1: False, 2: True, 3: False, 4: False, 5: True, 6: False, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: True, 11: True, 12: True, 13: False, 14: True, 15: True, 16: True, 17: True, 18: False, 19: False, 20: True, 21: False, 22: False, 23: False, 24: True, 25: False, 26: True, 27: True, 28: False, 29: True, 30: True, 31: False, 32: True, 33: True, 34: True, 35: True, 36: True, 37: False, 38: True, 39: False}}

ex.head()
  group  order   id type  of_interest
0     0      0  102    A        False
1     0      1  302    B        False
2     0      2  302    C         True
3     0      3  302    A        False
4     0      4  102    D        False
```

I want to create a column that for each combination of `group` and `id` return previous `type` where `of_interest == True`.

My first attempt involved querying for `of_interest == True`, therefore returned value only for these rows:

```
ex['prev_type_of_interest'] = ex \
    .query('of_interest == True') \
    .groupby(['group', 'id'])['type'] \
    .shift(1)
```

How can I return previous type of interest for every row?

Comment: What is expected output of first 10 rows?

Comment: it should be `[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'C', np.nan, 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'A']`

Comment: Can you explain more? Why not first value is `B` like previous row `2     0      2  302    C         True` because same group ?

Comment: For each subsequent row we check what was the last value of `type` of the same `id` under condition that it was `of_interest == True`. For first two rows (and `id`s `102` and `302` there was obviously no previous value of `type`. For third row, theres is previous value of `type` (`B`), but this is not of out interest (as `of_interest = False`). Then, for 4th row and `id = 302` within it, we have previous value of `type` equal to `C` and it is of our interest (`of_interest=True`), therefore we should return `C`. Hope that makes sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `shift` all rows per groups, then set missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and last replace missing values by previos non missing values by [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
ex1 = ex.groupby(['group', 'id']).shift()
ex['prev_type_of_interest'] = ex1['type'].where(ex1['of_interest'] == True)

ex['prev_type_of_interest'] = ex.groupby(['group', 'id'])['prev_type_of_interest'].ffill()   

print (ex.head(10))
  group  order   id type  of_interest prev_type_of_interest
0     0      0  102    A        False                   NaN
1     0      1  302    B        False                   NaN
2     0      2  302    C         True                   NaN
3     0      3  302    A        False                     C
4     0      4  102    D        False                   NaN
5     0      5  302    E         True                     C
6     0      6  302    D        False                     E
7     0      7  302    E         True                     E
8     0      8  302    A         True                     E
9     0      9  302    E         True                     A
```

Comment: Please note that expected output is different.

Comment: @Xaume - hmmm, I think now understand, can you verify edited answer?

Comment: yeah, it works like a charm! Would you be interested in looking into a follow-up question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016135/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-followed-by-another-value-with-variable-length-of-seq

Comment: @Xaume - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)