# How to check if a value is followed by another value with variable length of sequence

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with a series of events like below:

```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   ex2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'order': {266: 0, 267: 1, 268: 2, 269: 3, 270: 4, 271: 5, 739: 6, 740: 7, 741: 8, 742: 9, 743: 10, 744: 11, 1657: 12, 1658: 13, 1659: 14, 1660: 15, 1661: 16, 1662: 17, 1680: 18, 1681: 19, 1682: 20, 1683: 21, 1684: 22, 1685: 23, 1739: 24, 1740: 25, 1741: 26, 1742: 27, 1743: 28, 1744: 29, 2144: 30, 2145: 31, 2146: 32, 2147: 33, 2148: 34, 2149: 35, 2232: 36, 2233: 37, 2234: 38, 2235: 39, 2236: 40, 2237: 41, 2277: 42, 2278: 43, 2279: 44, 2280: 45, 2281: 46, 2282: 47, 2403: 48, 2404: 49, 2405: 50, 2406: 51, 2407: 52, 2408: 53, 2409: 54, 2410: 55, 2411: 56, 2412: 57, 2413: 58, 2414: 59, 2552: 60, 2553: 61, 2554: 62, 2555: 63, 2556: 64, 2557: 65, 2788: 66, 2789: 67, 2790: 68, 2791: 69, 2792: 70, 2793: 71}, 'group': {266: '0', 267: '0', 268: '0', 269: '0', 270: '0', 271: '0', 739: '0', 740: '0', 741: '0', 742: '0', 743: '0', 744: '0', 1657: '1', 1658: '1', 1659: '1', 1660: '1', 1661: '1', 1662: '1', 1680: '1', 1681: '1', 1682: '1', 1683: '1', 1684: '1', 1685: '1', 1739: '1', 1740: '1', 1741: '1', 1742: '1', 1743: '1', 1744: '1', 2144: '1', 2145: '1', 2146: '1', 2147: '1', 2148: '1', 2149: '1', 2232: '1', 2233: '1', 2234: '1', 2235: '1', 2236: '1', 2237: '1', 2277: '1', 2278: '1', 2279: '1', 2280: '1', 2281: '1', 2282: '1', 2403: '1', 2404: '1', 2405: '1', 2406: '1', 2407: '1', 2408: '1', 2409: '1', 2410: '1', 2411: '1', 2412: '1', 2413: '1', 2414: '1', 2552: '1', 2553: '1', 2554: '1', 2555: '1', 2556: '1', 2557: '1', 2788: '1', 2789: '1', 2790: '1', 2791: '1', 2792: '1', 2793: '1'}, 'id': {266: 301.0, 267: 301.0, 268: 302.0, 269: 302.0, 270: 302.0, 271: 303.0, 739: 304.0, 740: 304.0, 741: 304.0, 742: 305.0, 743: 306.0, 744: 306.0, 1657: 307.0, 1658: 301.0, 1659: 308.0, 1660: 308.0, 1661: np.nan, 1662: np.nan, 1680: 310.0, 1681: 301.0, 1682: 311.0, 1683: 311.0, 1684: 311.0, 1685: 312.0, 1739: 313.0, 1740: 313.0, 1741: 313.0, 1742: 313.0, 1743: 305.0, 1744: 305.0, 2144: 301.0, 2145: 301.0, 2146: 314.0, 2147: 305.0, 2148: 305.0, 2149: 305.0, 2232: 303.0, 2233: 303.0, 2234: 315.0, 2235: np.nan, 2236: np.nan, 2237: 316.0, 2277: 301.0, 2278: 301.0, 2279: 301.0, 2280: 305.0, 2281: 305.0, 2282: 317.0, 2403: 316.0, 2404: 316.0, 2405: 304.0, 2406: 304.0, 2407: 305.0, 2408: 310.0, 2409: 308.0, 2410: 318.0, 2411: 318.0, 2412: 305.0, 2413: 305.0, 2414: 319.0, 2552: 319.0, 2553: 320.0, 2554: 320.0, 2555: 320.0, 2556: np.nan, 2557: 310.0, 2788: 302.0, 2789: 321.0, 2790: 302.0, 2791: 302.0, 2792: 315.0, 2793: 322.0}, 'type': {266: 'A', 267: 'B', 268: 'C', 269: 'D', 270: 'E', 271: 'F', 739: 'A', 740: 'A', 741: 'C', 742: 'G', 743: 'A', 744: 'H', 1657: 'I', 1658: 'J', 1659: 'C', 1660: 'D', 1661: 'K', 1662: 'F', 1680: 'L', 1681: 'B', 1682: 'C', 1683: 'D', 1684: 'E', 1685: 'F', 1739: 'A', 1740: 'A', 1741: 'C', 1742: 'D', 1743: 'K', 1744: 'F', 2144: 'A', 2145: 'F', 2146: 'C', 2147: 'M', 2148: 'N', 2149: 'F', 2232: 'A', 2233: 'I', 2234: 'C', 2235: 'K', 2236: 'F', 2237: 'O', 2277: 'O', 2278: 'A', 2279: 'C', 2280: 'P', 2281: 'F', 2282: 'O', 2403: 'O', 2404: 'I', 2405: 'C', 2406: 'D', 2407: 'P', 2408: 'Q', 2409: 'R', 2410: 'O', 2411: 'C', 2412: 'P', 2413: 'F', 2414: 'F', 2552: 'R', 2553: 'O', 2554: 'C', 2555: 'D', 2556: 'S', 2557: 'L', 2788: 'C', 2789: 'B', 2790: 'C', 2791: 'E', 2792: 'F', 2793: 'O'}, 'is_active': {266: True, 267: True, 268: True, 269: False, 270: False, 271: True, 739: True, 740: True, 741: True, 742: True, 743: True, 744: True, 1657: True, 1658: True, 1659: True, 1660: False, 1661: True, 1662: True, 1680: False, 1681: True, 1682: True, 1683: False, 1684: False, 1685: True, 1739: True, 1740: True, 1741: True, 1742: False, 1743: True, 1744: True, 2144: True, 2145: True, 2146: True, 2147: True, 2148: True, 2149: True, 2232: True, 2233: True, 2234: True, 2235: True, 2236: True, 2237: True, 2277: True, 2278: True, 2279: True, 2280: True, 2281: True, 2282: True, 2403: True, 2404: True, 2405: True, 2406: False, 2407: True, 2408: False, 2409: True, 2410: True, 2411: True, 2412: True, 2413: True, 2414: True, 2552: True, 2553: True, 2554: True, 2555: False, 2556: True, 2557: False, 2788: True, 2789: True, 2790: True, 2791: False, 2792: True, 2793: True}, 'prev_event_type': {266: np.nan, 267: 'A', 268: np.nan, 269: 'C', 270: 'C', 271: np.nan, 739: np.nan, 740: 'A', 741: 'A', 742: np.nan, 743: np.nan, 744: 'A', 1657: np.nan, 1658: np.nan, 1659: np.nan, 1660: 'C', 1661: np.nan, 1662: np.nan, 1680: np.nan, 1681: 'J', 1682: np.nan, 1683: 'C', 1684: 'C', 1685: np.nan, 1739: np.nan, 1740: 'A', 1741: 'A', 1742: 'C', 1743: np.nan, 1744: 'K', 2144: 'B', 2145: 'A', 2146: np.nan, 2147: 'F', 2148: 'M', 2149: 'N', 2232: np.nan, 2233: 'A', 2234: np.nan, 2235: np.nan, 2236: np.nan, 2237: np.nan, 2277: 'F', 2278: 'O', 2279: 'A', 2280: 'F', 2281: 'P', 2282: np.nan, 2403: 'O', 2404: 'O', 2405: np.nan, 2406: 'C', 2407: 'F', 2408: np.nan, 2409: 'C', 2410: np.nan, 2411: 'O', 2412: 'P', 2413: 'P', 2414: np.nan, 2552: 'F', 2553: np.nan, 2554: 'O', 2555: 'C', 2556: np.nan, 2557: np.nan, 2788: 'C', 2789: np.nan, 2790: np.nan, 2791: 'C', 2792: 'C', 2793: np.nan}, 'is_of_interest': {266: False, 267: False, 268: False, 269: False, 270: True, 271: False, 739: False, 740: False, 741: False, 742: False, 743: False, 744: False, 1657: False, 1658: False, 1659: False, 1660: False, 1661: False, 1662: False, 1680: False, 1681: False, 1682: False, 1683: False, 1684: True, 1685: False, 1739: False, 1740: False, 1741: False, 1742: False, 1743: False, 1744: False, 2144: False, 2145: False, 2146: False, 2147: False, 2148: False, 2149: False, 2232: False, 2233: False, 2234: False, 2235: False, 2236: False, 2237: False, 2277: False, 2278: False, 2279: False, 2280: False, 2281: False, 2282: False, 2403: False, 2404: False, 2405: False, 2406: False, 2407: False, 2408: False, 2409: False, 2410: False, 2411: False, 2412: False, 2413: False, 2414: False, 2552: False, 2553: False, 2554: False, 2555: False, 2556: False, 2557: False, 2788: False, 2789: False, 2790: False, 2791: True, 2792: False, 2793: False}})
```

I need to define if an event of `type == 'C'` results in an event of `type == 'E'` for particular `group` and `id` combination (so all operations will pe performed on `ex2.groupby(['group', 'id']`). I know that event of `type == 'C'` results in event of `type == 'E'` if there is no active (`is_active == 1`) event between `C` and `E`. I currently have a backward information about previous active event type contained in `prev_active_type` column. So for example:

- for 5th row (`order == 4`), which is of type `E` I know that `prev_active_type == 'C'` - therefore, `C` led to `E`.
- on the other hand, for 9th row (`order == 8`), `C` doesn't result in `E`.

What I need to obtain is a column that would tell me if event of `type == 'C'` resulted in event of type `E` (`new_column == True`) or not (`new_column == False`). I think creating an `is_of_interest` column which indicates if `type == E` is a good start, but I can't figure out how to achieve my goal from that. THe issue is that there is a variable number of events between `C` and `E` - sometimes there is none, sometimes there is one, two or event three...

The expected output is:

```
ex2['expected_output2'] = {266: False, 267: False, 268: True, 269: False, 270: False, 271: False, 739: False, 740: False, 741: False, 742: False, 743: False, 744: False, 1657: False, 1658: False, 1659: False, 1660: False, 1661: False, 1662: False, 1680: False, 1681: False, 1682: True, 1683: False, 1684: False, 1685: False, 1739: False, 1740: False, 1741: False, 1742: False, 1743: False, 1744: False, 2144: False, 2145: False, 2146: False, 2147: False, 2148: False, 2149: False, 2232: False, 2233: False, 2234: False, 2235: False, 2236: False, 2237: False, 2277: False, 2278: False, 2279: False, 2280: False, 2281: False, 2282: False, 2403: False, 2404: False, 2405: False, 2406: False, 2407: False, 2408: False, 2409: False, 2410: False, 2411: False, 2412: False, 2413: False, 2414: False, 2552: False, 2553: False, 2554: False, 2555: False, 2556: False, 2557: False, 2788: False, 2789: False, 2790: True, 2791: False, 2792: False, 2793: False}.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to give a small overview of the general idea first, below you find a working code example. I assume that your data is in correct order.
The following happens:

- Give every entry a 'connection number', where a new connection starts at every occurance of a `C` row as well as **after** each `E` row.
- Then, for each of these connections, check if the following conditions apply:

  - The connection must have one row with a `C` and one row with an `E`, because of how the connections are created in the first step, `C` and `E` rows will only happen in the first and last row respectively.
  - All rows between the first and last row must have `'is_active' == False`

---

Here a working example:

```
# I removed your rows as they are not needed
ex2.drop(['prev_event_type', 'is_of_interest'], axis=1, inplace=True)

def is_valid_connection(connection):
    is_valid = (
            (connection['type'] == 'C').any() and
            (connection['type'] == 'E').any() and
            (~connection.iloc[1:-1]['is_active']).all()
    )
    return pd.Series({'result': is_valid})


ex2['connection_number'] = ((ex2['type'] == 'C') | (ex2['type'] == 'E').shift(1, fill_value=False)).cumsum()
valid_connection_ids = ex2.groupby(['group', 'id', 'connection_number']).apply(is_valid_connection)
ex2 = ex2.merge(valid_connection_ids, left_on=['group', 'id', 'connection_number'], right_index=True)
ex2.loc[ex2['type'] != 'C', 'result'] = False
ex2 = ex2.drop('connection_number', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation for the solution to the problem above:

- Sort Dataframe (by order or group,id)

```
ex2.sort_values(by=['group', 'id'], inplace=True)
```

- Group Dataframe by previous event type:

```
grouped_df = ex2.groupby(['group', 'id', 'prev_event_type']).aggregate({
    'group': 'first',
    'id': 'first',
    'prev_event_type': 'first',
    'type': lambda x: list(x),
    'is_active': lambda x: list(x)
})
```

- Iterate through zipped values to find the sequence of E (can be improved):

```
def check_next(nexts, actives):
    check = False
    for n, a in zip(nexts, actives):
        if n != 'E':
            check = a
        else:
            return not check
    return False

grouped_df['output'] = grouped_df.apply(lambda x: check_next(x['type'], x['is_active']) if x['prev_event_type'] == 'C' else False, axis=1)
```

And now you have every group, id pair labelled where an E event occurred before C, such that there are no active-events in between.

Let me know if this helps!

[image: View Result Here]